# Is it possible to have transparent overlays from another route?

Tags: flutter

So, I have the following code which allows me to push a semi-transparent overlay.

```
Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
    opaque: false,
    pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) =>
        LoadingScreen()));
```

Now I would like for me to do this as a named route so that I can retrieve the current route name from `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name`. So my question is how do I define this to accomplish my goal?